# Do I need to put everything in app/workers for sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm currently migrating from DJ to sidekiq and have a lot of plain old ruby objects that I would use like so:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(SomeService.new(id))
```

I thought I could just move `SomeService` into the `app/workers` folder and add `include Sidekiq::Worker` but it doesn't ever go into the sidekiq queue and just calls performs on the spot

```
class SomeService
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def initialize(id)
    @some_instance = SomeClass.find_by(id: id)
  end 

  def perform
    @some_instance.do_something
  end
end
```

so instead I have to create a sidekiq worker to call the service

```
class SomeServiceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    SomeService.new(id).perform
  end
end
```

Is there a way to just use the SomeService, which contains an initialize method and perform method so I don't have to create a worker to call my service object?

Comment: Sorry, Workers must have an empty initialize method.  Arguments go into `perform`.  ActiveJob is the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Only one mistake what you did, you forget to add "Worker" word in your class name in the first file!

```
class SomeServiceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def initialize(id)
    @some_instance = SomeClass.find_by(id: id)
  end 

  def perform
    @some_instance.do_something
  end
end
```

And this code will run your worker

```
SomeServiceWorker.new(id).perform
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  Sidekiq Workers can be named anything but they must include Sidekiq::Worker, have an empty initialize method and a perform method which takes any necessary arguments.

Comment: @MikePerham  by empty initialize method, do you mean no initialize method at all, or just no arguments?

Comment: I mean no arguments.

Comment: The empty initialize method isn't required in the latest versions? At least I'm using the workers without.

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq doesn't care much about where the files are and/or how they are named, as long as they include `Sidekiq::Worker`. The convention though, is to put all the workers in the `app/workers` directory and to name them as `MyWorker`.

You can then call them as:

```rb
MyWorker.perform_async params
```

Answer (score 0):

These won't be background job:

```
# This won't do
SomeWorker.new(*args).perform
# This is also won't do
SomeWorker.new.perform(*args)
```

You have to use perform without create the class instance:

```
# This is correct:
SomeWorker.perform_async(*args)
# This is also correct:
Sidekiq::Client.push('class' => SomeWorker, 'args' => *args)
```

So, you cannot have initialize method in for sidekiq worker.

Assuming those are your only code, so:

```
class SomeServiceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    some_instance = SomeClass.find(id)
    some_instance.do_something
  end
end
```

If SomeService is actually more complex, the best practice is to do what you do:

```
class SomeServiceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    SomeService.new(id).perform
  end
end
```